# How to caches API response in a service in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular component which gets data from a service of common phrases.  I've included the relevant code here, which is the component getting the data from an API.

My problem is that this component is used in many areas in a nested form, and so the API call to getPhrases() gets called multiple times.

I've tried to cache this in my service, but that hasn't worked - maybe because the service is being created each time as well?

What's the best way to only call the API once per session?

```
export class MentionDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  phrases: any[];

  constructor(
    public mentionService: MentionService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mentionService.getPhrases()
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.phrases = result;              
        },
        () => { });

  }

}
```

Here's the service:

```
export class MentionService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    private phrases$: Observable<string[]>;

    public getPhrases(): Observable<string[]> {
        if (!this.phrases$) {
            this.phrases$ = this.http.get<string[]>(this.baseUrl + '/getAutocompletePhrasesList');
        }
        return this.phrases$;
    }
}
```

This is how I call my directive:

```
<input matInput mention formControlName="message" required>
```

Comment: `maybe because the service is being created each time as well?` Well, where ARE you providing the service?

Comment: @AT82 I'm injecting the service into the mention component, but the component is being called on each input.  So I think what happens is in a form I have 10 inputs, each input has a call to the mention component which then calls the service.

Comment: I'm not talking about injecting, but **providing**, where is the service provided? It should be in root to be a shared service.

Comment: @AT82 that could be the issue, It's in it's own module which is then imported (and then exported) in a shared module

Answer (score 0):

If you try simple snippet:

```
const obs = this.http.get....;
obs.subscribe(() => console.log('test'));
obs.subscribe(() => console.log('test'));
```

You will see that http request is sent each time you subscribe, too avoid that you just need `pipe(share())`.

Comment: That hasn't worked in my example if I do this.mentionService.getPhrases().pipe(share()).subscribe then it still keeps calling the API

Answer (score 0):

I normally use localStorage to cache loaded datas from API. Then I need to check the localStogage first. If localStorage is empty, I just call the API again.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('phrases') === null){
    this.mentionService.getPhrases()
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.phrases = result;
          localStorage.setItem('phrases', result);
        },
        () => { });
    }else{
      this.phrases = localStorage.getItem('phrases');
    }

  }
```